# Can't get hyperparameters to pass in as arguments to a sagemaker estimator when using a custom docker image

Tags: python, docker, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I just need to pass hyperparameters to my training job when using a custom docker image

When I remove the custom image "image_uri" I can see the arguments being passed, but things don't work as I need the custom image.

I also tried using just a regular sagemaker

```
Estimator(
            image_uri=image_uri,
            role=role,
            instance_count=1,
            instance_type="ml.m5.large",
            hyperparameters=hyperparameters,
            output_path=f"s3://{ML_S3_BUCKET}/models/{training_job_name}",
        )
```

as well

Starting the training job

```
hyperparameters={
        "epochs": 3000,
        "learning_rate": 0.0005,
        "input_size": 57,
        "hidden_size": 40,
        "output_size": 1,
        "patience": 1000,
        "hidden_layer_count": 4,
        "is_alpha": False,
    }
estimator = PyTorch(
            entry_point="train/train_illuvitar_neural_net.py",
            image_uri=image_uri,
            role=role,
            py_version="py310",
            framework_version="2.0",
            instance_count=1,
            instance_type="ml.m5.large",
            hyperparameters=hyperparameters,
            output_path=f"s3://{ML_S3_BUCKET}/models/{training_job_name}",
        )
```

Dockerfile

```
# Start with an official PyTorch image as a base
FROM pytorch/pytorch:2.0.0-cuda11.7-cudnn8-runtime

# Install any additional libraries and tools needed
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libgomp1
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev gcc

# &&
# rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install the necessary Python packages
COPY requirements_sm_training.txt /opt/ml/code/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /opt/ml/code/requirements.txt

# Probably don't need this
RUN pip3 install sagemaker-training

# Copy the training script
COPY train/train_illuvitar_neural_net.py /opt/ml/code/train
RUN chmod +x /opt/ml/code/train
COPY shared/ /opt/ml/code/shared/
COPY helper/ /opt/ml/code/helper/

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /opt/ml/code
ENV PATH="/opt/ml/code:${PATH}"
```

Training script arg parser

```
def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    is_local = os.environ.get("ISLOCAL")
    default_model_dir = (
        "./local_model_storage" if is_local else "/opt/ml/model"
    )  # os.environ.get("SM_MODEL_DIR")

    parser.add_argument("--epochs", type=int, default=500, help="Number of training epochs")
    parser.add_argument("--learning_rate", type=float, help="Learning rate for the optimizer")
    parser.add_argument("--batch_size", type=int, default=1024, help="Batch size for training")
    parser.add_argument("--model_dir", type=str, default=default_model_dir)
    parser.add_argument("--input_size", type=int, default=57, help="Input size for the model")
    parser.add_argument(
        "--hidden_size", type=int, default=40, help="Number of neurons in the hidden layer"
    )
    parser.add_argument("--output_size", type=int, default=1, help="Output size for the model")
    parser.add_argument("--patience", type=int, default=200, help="Patience for early stopping")
    parser.add_argument("--min_delta_for_early_stopping", type=float, default=0.03)
    parser.add_argument("--hidden_layer_count", type=int, default=3, help="Number of hidden layers")
    parser.add_argument(
        "--is_alpha", type=bool, default=False, help="Is this an alpha model?"
    )  # sagemaker doesn't support actions lik "store_true"
    parser.add_argument("--training_job_name", type=str, default="sagemaker-run-1684176842-32dd")
    parser.add_argument("--experiment_name", type=str, default="firstexperiment")

    parser.add_argument("--run_number", type=int, default=1)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    return args
```

What do I need to modify to get this to work? Or am I fundamentally misunderstanding something here?

I can't for the life of me find an example of this anywhere, anytime an example has a custom image it doesn't have hyperparameters specified, any example with hyperparameters doesn't use a custom image.

Comment: How are you trying to access the hyperparameters in your training script? Fundamentally, SageMaker will create a file at `opt/ml/input/config/hyperparameters.json` which your script can read from. Are you saying this file isn't present when using a custom container?

One example that might be helpful: [Hyperparameter injection](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker-fundamentals/create-training-job/create_training_job_hyperparameter_injection.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Sagemaker [does not](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/sagemaker-doesn-t-support-argparse-actions/12467) support `argparse` actions. You can either use [HfArgumentParser](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v4.2.2/_modules/transformers/hf_argparser.html) or alternatively retrieve the parameters from a JSON file that SageMaker provides.

For example, you can modify your /opt/ml/code/train script to invoke you Python script as follows:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

params_file="/opt/ml/input/config/hyperparameters.json"
# forms a string like "--param1 foo --param2 bar" from json file.
hyperparameters=$(jq -r 'to_entries[] | "--\(.key) \(.value)"' "$params_file")

python train.py $hyperparameters
```

Please note that this solution requires `jq` to be installed in the container. You can include the installation of `jq` in your Dockerfile:

```bash
# Dockerfile
RUN apt install jq -y
```

While this is a basic solution, it should work effectively. You can further refine it to suit your specific requirements.